# Notepadd++ insert without replace

Tags: regex, notepad++

Check this list below

```
57
Nome: O Paradoxo Cloverfield  


58
Nome: Batman: Gotham by Gaslight  

59
Nome: Batman: Gotham by Gaslight  


60
Nome: Batman: Gotham by Gaslight  

61
Nome: Batman: Gotham by Gaslight  


62
Nome: Vende-se Esta Casa  

...
```

So, I need add "Linha: " before these numbers, like this:

```
Linha: 57
Nome: O paraxodo Cloverfield

Linha: 58
Nome: Batman: Gotham by Gaslight

...
```

And I'm finding successfully the numbers with this regex: **^[0-9]+**
But in the replace option, I don't know what should I do to insert "Linha:" before without losing the numbers. So, can you help me? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a group and the $1 reference to access the value of the group should do the job:

Find what: `(^[0-9]+)`

Replace with: `Linha: $1`

I ran this on NP++ v7.5.1.